# Chrome extension Markdown editor using Ace with open & save to desktop

Tags: chrome, markdown

As the title suggests, does there exist a decent extension for Chrome that allows editing of Markdown (preferably using [Ace](https://ace.c9.io/)) with the option to open and save files from the local hard drive?

I would use this as a bare bones replacement for Visual Studio Code on a PC where I do not have the opportunity to install additional software except Chrome extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

- [Zed Code Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zed-code-editor/pfmjnmeipppmcebplngmhfkleiinphhp) by Zef Hemel ([GitHub](https://github.com/zedapp/zed))
- [Caret](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/caret/fljalecfjciodhpcledpamjachpmelml) by Thomas Wilburn ([GitHub](https://github.com/thomaswilburn/Caret))

Comment: sorry i thought finding extension links from main website is easy, added chrome extension links now, Zed has two extensions the one linked opens files from your disk.

Comment: Great recommendations! I have used Caret extensively today and it has been very productive.